# Any pictorial resources for the first chapter in maseches Kla'im?

Tags: product-recommendation, mishna, pictures, artscroll, maseches-kilayim

The seffer by Y. Feliks, *Klei Zeraim ViHarkava* is quoted extensively in Artscroll's mishnayos. Does this seffer have pictures like the author's other work *Hatzomeach ViHachai*?

Or are there any other good resources for pictorial help on the first chapter in maseches Kla'im? Preferably online. I'm having trouble envisioning these items, and many of the plant names, even the names used by Artscroll are hard to Google.

Comment: The title given on Google Books suggests that that book has a lot of pictures: [‎‫כלאי זרעים והרכבה‬: ‫מסכת כלאים : משנה, תוספתא וירושלמי לפרקים א־ב : בירור הסוגיות ורקען הבוטני־חקלאי בלווית 188 תמונות ושירטוטים‬ - ‫יהודה פליקס‬](http://books.google.com/books/about/%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%99_%D7%96%D7%A8%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%95%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%91%D7%94.html?id=EW4PAQAAIAAJ). (Snippet view only, sorry).

Comment: @Fred Thanks! Now I need to get my hands on one....

Comment: @user6591 re your comment: There are at least [six copies in libraries stateside](http://worldcat.org/oclc/42037536) and [one in Israel](http://worldcat.org/oclc/233320382).

Comment: @msh210 Wow. Thats awesome. Not at all what I meant, but that's really great.